# Constant updates to future employer on present situation

Tags: professionalism, communication, job-offer, hiring-process, manager

I recently signed an offer letter with another department within the same organization I work at and I'm wondering how best to handle a few *issues*. Unfortunately, due to immigration delays, a quick switch may not be possible, so, I'm struggling with how to handle a few things regarding my future manager/department.

1. I find myself constantly checking up with the office that handles immigration matters within the organization to get the latest information on the process, and I eagerly want to update the department I'm hoping to start with soon, with this information. I'm not sure where to draw the line between being helpful/enthusiastic, but not come across as a nuisance at the same time.
2. Is there a need to keep in regular touch with the future manager? I asked during the interview process if there was anything I need to start learning now before I join the team, and they said none at that moment, but seeing as the wait may take a while, do I need some sort of constant communication with them? I am a little anxious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You could ask the office that handles immigration matters if they'd be okay with weekly status updates.
2. I'd maybe send them an email right now informing your future manager about your current situation and ask if, in light of that, their original recommendation that no prep work is needed still stands. Once your immigration papers are successfully processed maybe you could send your future manager an email saying something to the effect of "*My immigration paperwork is now complete! In light of that I'm wondering what my start date is?*" or something.

Constant communication is not needed and might prejudice your future manager against you (ie. he might see you as needy or something)